# Chunked large JSON POST using .NET HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am sending data for up to 10K users in JSON format to a http endpoint in a .NET Core MVC server app. The JSON is built slowly user by user and is custom (JSON.NET just isn't usable for me). I use a HttpClient and I basically want to send the JSON chunk by chunk so I don't have to accumulate it all at once and sit with a multi-megabyte string in memory for each request, hurting my large object heap. I cannot find and equivalent for HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream that was used earlier.
StreamContent doesn't seem to fit the bill, I even found PushStreamContent, PipeStream etc. but I don't see a way how to do it, haven't found any answers on SO... Last option I can think of seems to inherit from Stream and implement it myself, but there must be a better way, many people must've encountered this problem.
Any advice?

Comment: 10k users?! how big is the file?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not really possible to parse JSON in bits, it's all or nothing unfortunately.

Comment: Do you compress the data? 10K doesn't seem like a huge amount of data.

Comment: Well each user has some data and potentially even an image, the resulting JSON string tends to be several megabytes which seems really unnecessary when I use StringContent, that StringBuilder I use to accumulate the JSON and the resulting string instance will both go directly to LOH :(

I don't need to parse JSON, I am building it manually and would ideally want to send 10K chunks with JSON for each user separately. I just need a way to push those partial strings into the request stream...